# My blur dial is missing in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur

Previously there was a blur dial in my Photoshop by which I could change the blur amount directly on the image. The dial was just outside of the blur pin area (inner circle around the pin). But now the dial is missing by anyway and I can't bring it back.

[image: u]

[image]

Please have a look on the second image. I have pin (#1/blue arrow) but there is no dial (#2/red arrow)

Can someone help me to turn on the blur dial again?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if this is one of those things where deleting the preferences would help...

Comment: No, I just have checked by deleting photoshop preference settings by pressing ctl+alt+shift during opening up Photoshop and thereafter deleting the preference settings, but could not help.

Comment: I have no idea why it's not showing up. Maybe you should post this in the Adobe forums.

Comment: I think this was removed? Maybe in CC 2019? I don't have it either. I can't imagine this would be in the release notes, but maybe we can see when they removed it. (Probably the same time they removed the check boxes in Acrobat comments)

Answer (score 1):

The *Edit Pins* can be turned on and off.

Select *View > Show > Edit Pins*.

(I found the answer in [Adobe's forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1146166) googling "blur dial is missing in Photoshop")

Comment: No, actually it shows/hides pins on the image. But there is still no pin dial (by holding the cursor on pin dial one can increase/decrease the blurriness. It is just like a dial wrist watch).

Comment: I have added a second picture to describe my problem more precisely. Please look at the second image.

Comment: I can confirm on my PS 2019 CC that as @Wolff has said, that settings toggle located in View>Show>Edit Pins *should* control both edit pins ***and*** on-image blur dial: it not doing so seems like either an install bug or, according to what I see on the Adobe forums, possible graphics driver issues...

Comment: I think so as there is no indication that PIN and PIN DIAL can be showed or hided separately. So it might be an issue of graphic driver incompatability.